# Stopping the audio after playing with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

Hi guys hope you all can help me with this issue.

What I would like to do is when user left view B to view A, the audio plays, when user left view A to view B, the audio stops.

so when user left view B (removing viewB from superview) back to the main view which is view A, the methods playIT & hahaPlay will be called. When user left view A to View B (view A add subview B) the stopPlaying method will be called instead. But here's my problem, even the stopPlaying method is called, the audio is not stopped. I realised the alert is shown but for some reason the statement> `[audioPlayer stop];` is not functioning.

I've already defined the audio player in header file just fyi.

All the methods below are in the `viewcontroller` called soundView.

Sorry I might be doing the whole thing in a wrong way, maybe some of you can enlighten me and correct my mistakes?

```
-(void)playIT{

    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"6431" 
                                               ofType:@"aiff"];
    fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                   initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
}

-(void)hahaPlay{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"playing" message:@" playing" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yep, I did." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; 
    [alert release]; 
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    if(![audioPlayer isPlaying]){

        [audioPlayer play];
    }

- (void)stopPlaying{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Stop playing" message:@"Stop playing" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yep, I did." otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show]; 
    [alert release]; 

    [audioPlayer stop];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're losing the reference somewhere by mistake, try setting a breakpoint near the stop call, and checking `audioPlayer` just in case that the `audioPlayer` is `nil`. Just saying because usually this is the reason for most of these type of problems for me...

Also will the following work?

```
[audioPlayer pause]
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
```